# Run Android Service with GPS/Data turn on/off by it self

Tags: android, service, gps, root

We have to provide application that track our field workers locations by gps logging that can track workers real time. These devices provided by company that runs lollipop.
GPS Logger Service is running well until workers turn off GPS and Data.

Problem is.
Is there any way to prevent on/off GPS and Data by user?.
How we should distribute these type of applications to users?.
Does rooting the device will help on this situation?

Can someone help me on this situation.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you root the devices, you can use sqlite3 executable to modify settings.db. 
So, for example, you can monitor GPS and Mobile Data settings and update them if they are changed.